# Difficulties with call a method from a subclass in python - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute

Tags: python, multithreading, class, inheritance

I want to call a method in a subclass using threading. This method is a while loop that executes a method in the main class.

I don't understand the error, as I interpret it, I am doing something wrong with the inheritance.

A minimal example of my code:

```
class Echo(WebSocket):

    def __init__(self, client, server, sock, address):
        super().__init__(server, sock, address)
        self.modbus = client

    def temp_control(self, value)
        do_something(value)
        return True

class Temperature_Control3(Echo):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.value

    def control(self, value):
        while True:
            print("temp_controll")
            self.temp_control(self, value) #call the method in Echo class
            time.sleep(4)

def main():
    with ModbusClient(host=HOST, port=PORT) as client:
        client.connect()
        time.sleep(0.01)

        print("Websocket server on port %s" % PORTNUM)
        server = SimpleWebSocketServer('', PORTNUM, partial(Echo, client))


        control = Temperature_Control3()
        t3 = threading.Thread(target=control.control, args=('', 'get'), daemon=False)
        t3.start()


        try:
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=server.serveforever())
            t1.start()
            for thread in threading.enumerate():
                print(thread.name)
        finally:
            server.close()
```

t1 is starting well but t2 can't because of the error above. I have little experience with OOP programming, maybe someone here can help, thanks!

Edit: I got a new Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "websocketserver6_threading.py", line 566, in <module>
    main()
  File "websocketserver6_threading.py", line 545, in main
    control = Temperature_Control3()
  File "websocketserver6_threading.py", line 516, in __init__
    super().__init__()
TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'client', 'server', 'sock', and 'address'
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you're referring to `Temperature_Controll3.temp_controll` directly, which is the wrong way to do it.

Instead, you need to create an *instance* of that class:

```
t3 = Temperature_Controll3()
```

And then refer to the method of the instance:

```
target=t3.temp_controll
```

However, there are also other problems.  The `temp_controll()` function is infinitely recursive:

```
def temp_controll(self, value):
    while True:
        print("temp_controll")
        self.temp_controll(self, value)
        time.sleep(4)
```

The function calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself... forever.  I have no idea what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Thank you, the function should call the temp_controll funcion in the class Echo, I have modified this:  control = Temperature_Control3() and t3 = threading.Thread(target=control.control, args=('', 'get'), daemon=False) but now I got another error: TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'client', 'server', 'sock', and 'address' ... Edit: I will Edit my entry Post.